# Inductance of a single conductor

Tags: power-supply, electromagnetism, inductance, magnetic-flux

Which is the correct expression for the inductance of a single conductor? I see 2 different formulaes for the same in different sources.

[image: https://www.eeweb.com/tools/wire-inductance]

**Formula 1.**

Ref: https://www.eeweb.com/tools/wire-inductance

[image]

**Formula 2**

Ref. https://www.electrical4u.com/inductance-in-power-transmission-line/

[image]
[image]

Note: In Formula 2,inductance is calculated for unit length. D is the distance upto which you need to consider the effect of magnetic flux (ideally infinite) for inductance calculation. Formula 2 is the one I have studied in college and I understand the derivation, but Formula 1 is from a reputed Electrical engineering online site. Now I am confused.

Comment: F2 is correct for long (read: endless) lines as power lines, for example, while F1 is for short conductors, where you have to take l into consideration. Make l→∞ and see what happens.

Comment: @Janka Surely inductance depends on the loop area. So you need to know the return path to determine the inductance.

Comment: Yes, normally we talk about the inductance of a closed loop. Nevertheless we could still calculate the inductance of a piece of straight conductor. That is what Iam trying to understand.